# How to unit test RxSwift which has debounce before output the next?

Tags: ios, reactive-programming, rx-swift, debouncing

I am using RxSwift for reactive programming and want to test my View Model.
I have debounce like this:

In View Model:

```
let personNameMessage = input.personName.debounce(0.5).map { name -> String in
    return "Person Name = \(name)"
}
return Driver.just(personNameMessage)
```

and then in Test Case:

```
let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
let personNameInput = scheduler.createHotObservable([next(100, "John Doe")])
let personObserver = scheduler.createObserver(String.self)
output.personNameWelcome
    .asObservable()
    .subscribe(personObserver)
    .disposed(disposeBag)

scheduler.start()

print(observer.events)
```

But it did not emitting the event. I've try adding `scheduler.advanceBy(550)` after `scheduler.start()` but the results are the same.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Debounce works so don't test it. Map works so don't test it. The only thing you need to test in that block of code is the function you pass to map. (And frankly, that function is so trivial that I wouldn't bother testing *it* either.)

Answer (score 5):

Given the fact you're using `debounce` without specifying a scheduler, I'm assuming `personName` is actually a `Driver` - in which case, it will use `DriverSharingStrategy.scheduler` as its default scheduler.

By default, that leads to `MainScheduler.instance`, but in a test scenario, you can simply mock using the `SharingScheduler` class.

```
SharingScheduler.mock(scheduler: yourTestScheduler) {
    /// make all your assertions here.
    /// the `mock()` will make `DriverSharingStrategy.scheduler` return
    /// your test scheduler, instead of the default one.
}
```

Comment: If you are writing your own epics that use a scheduler, you will need to use `SharingScheduler.make()` instead of `MainScheduler.instance`. In non-unit tests it will be the equivalent to calling `MainScheduler`, but now it will be mock-able.
I learned this from RayWenderlich: https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/testing-your-rxswift-code-raywenderlich-com/54681/5

Comment: @ErikAllen you have linked to my own comment on the tutorial I myself have written :)

Comment: Well now I feel a little silly. But I still stand by my comment; I had to do further research to get my non-driver working and that link explained it well enough.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is not in debounce method itself
however, if your issue in testing the debounce method you have to change the resolution of the test scheduler to know more about [scheduler resolution](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7408-testing-your-rxswift-code#toc-anchor-009)

But the real issue here is to test Observable works on different schedulers since debounce usually uses a different scheduler

Solution : to use SharingScheduler.make()

```html
import RxCocoa

let personNameMessage = input.personName.debounce(0.5,scheduler: SharingScheduler.make()).map { name -> String in
    return "Person Name = \(name)"
}
return Driver.just(personNameMessage)
//The test case
func testDebounce() throws {
    let schedular = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0, resolution: 0.001)
    SharingScheduler.mock(scheduler: schedular) {
        let observer = schedular.createObserver(Double.self)
        schedular.createColdObservable([.next(0, 0)]).bind(to: observer).disposed(by: bag)
        schedular.start()

        XCTAssertEqual(oObserver.events, [.next(700, 100)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you really think about it, you don't need to test whether the debounce works (of course it works, RxSwift has several tests that prove it works,) all you need to test is that it is part of the chain. For that, you can simply load the text of the `.swift` file and run a regex over it.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the code above is simplified version of my actual code. I don't want to check the debounce, but I would like to test if personNameMessage is `output` a value.